# Field of definition of a subvariety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a variety over a field $\overline{k}$ (where $k$ is a field which is not algebraically closed). Each closed point of $X$ is defined over some finite extension $\ell/ k$, which means that it corresponds to a morphism $\textrm{Spec } \ell \to X$. Does this also work for open or closed subvarieties?

To be clear: let $U \subset X$ be an open or closed subvariety, then can you always find a finite extension $\ell / k$ and a variety $U' $ over $\ell$ such that $U = U' \times_{\ell} \overline{k}$? If not, what kind of conditions would you need on $U$ in order for this to be true?

Comment: This is fairly clear in the case that $X$ is affine and the subvariety $Y$ is closed. Then $X$ is Spec of some polynomial ring mod a finite set of polynomials, and $Y$ is Spec of that thing mod a further finite set of polynomials. There are finitely many coefficients in these polynomials and they generate a finite extension $L$ of $k$; $Y$ and $X$ are both definable over this. You can hope to glue this argument together for the general case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always true at least for a Noetherian variety. Notice that if you prove  this for a closed subset, then the same field will work for the complement. So, let $Z\subset X$ be a closed subset. Use Noetherianness to cover $X$ by finitely many affine open sets and thus you can reduce to affine varieties. Then, use Qiaochu Yuan's argument above.

Comment: You are using finiteness to ensure that the compositum of the various extension fields is still finite?  Is it obvious that we can choose the $U'$ so that they glue?

Comment: Once the complement is defined over a field (finite extension of $k$), same applies to $U$. The gluing issues don't appear.

Comment: Why not?  We write $X = U_1 \cup \cdots \cup U_n$, then choose $U_i'$, each defined over some finite extension $k\subset l$, with $U_i \cong U_i' \times_l \overline{k} $.  We're looking for an $X'$ with $X\cong X' \times_l \overline{k}$.  What is the gluing data to get this $X$?  I would not be surprised if there were some theorem that says, for example, that the property of being "defined over $l$" can be checked on stalks, but if you're using something like that I'd like to see it made explicit.